# How to put a keyBoard in UIAlertView?

Tags: swift

Here is my code for the UIAlertView with the textField:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


@IBAction func addReminder(sender: AnyObject) {




    var tField: UITextField!



    func configurationTextField(textField: UITextField!)
    {
        print("generating the TextField")
        textField.placeholder = "Enter a Reminder"
        tField = textField


    }

    func handleCancel(alertView: UIAlertAction!)
    {
        print("Cancelled !!")
    }

    var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Reminder", message: "", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler(configurationTextField)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler:handleCancel))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .Default, handler:{ (UIAlertAction) in
        print("Done !!")

        print("Item : \(tField.text!)")
    }))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: {
        print("completion block")
    })
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(reminder, forKey: "toDoList")


       }
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.





}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return reminder.count
}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = reminder[indexPath.row]

            return cell
}


override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    tableView.reloadData()

}




override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }


}
```

So I wanna add a keyBoard to the UIAlertView. So when you run the code and press on the text the keyBoard will pop up. So how would I program it??

Comment: let me guess all you want is to when user presses on textfield , keyboard will pop up?Because i dont think you can attach a keyboard to an UIAlertView

Comment: When you tap on a text field, a keyboard automatically pops up.